# Scrolling effect-Overlapping images with scrolling

Tags: jquery, z-index, javascript, css-animations

Please see this image first(sorry for inconvenience) [animation effect](http://postimg.org/image/6ali5d7ht/)

Now,My question is:
I want to give such effect.
Does anyone know using which technology I will be able to do it?

It is for touch devices.when user tap on first time,it will show grid of images and user will be able to scroll through these images.

Basically It can be done with the help of **javascript and jquery library using z-index** property.
But I dont have in-depth knowledge to do such scrolling effect.
Any help will be appreciated.
thank you.

jsfiddle: [check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6kws/1/)

**UPDATE**: Code so far (it is very basic,only displaying overlapping images)

html part

```
 <div id="div1">You can also drag here!</div>

                <div id="div2">
                <p>Scroll Me!</p>                

            <img src="images/2.jpg"  id="drag22"> 
            <img src="images/3.jpg"  id="drag32">


                </div> <!--div2-->
```

script part

```
<style  type="text/css">
#div2
{

    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    border:2px;
    border-color:blue;
    position:relative;
}


#drag22 {
/* bird; */
z-index:22;
position:absolute;
top: 100px; 
left:10px;
/* opacity:0.7; */
/* height:40px; */
/*float:right;*/
} 
#drag32 {
/* graph */
z-index:21;
position:absolute;
top: 30px; 
left:60px;
}

</style>
```

Comment: you need to show your code..what have you done so far?

Comment: I have put very basic code. @VAGABOND

Comment: try jsfiddle.net...for such mission its ideal..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that will not be an animation.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/gRaDf/

```
var width =225;
var height=95;
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
     clonedimage = $("img#"+i).clone();
    clonedimage.attr("id", i+1);
    clonedimage.css("width", width-(i*10));
    clonedimage.css("height", height-(i*5));
     clonedimage.appendTo( "div" );

}
```

Comment: but it is using a single image only, I have many images..check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T6kws/1/

Comment: @jack : then i dont get how u want it. You want the effect u see in the gif u linked, or u want the effect, that when a user scrolls down it loads new images?

Comment: Oh okay! well, that is just an example with single image, actually there are different images (which will be fetched form database dynamically)

Comment: I show u how u can do an effect like that. The real implementation is up to you :)
U asked for the technik: use jQuery.clone() to dublicate the image then use jQuery.css() to alter the css propeties how u want it. Thats all.